# SQL: create primary key from foreign key and attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, create-table

I'm trying to create the primary key of a table from one foreign key
and from one attribute of the table itself.

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    attribute int,
    FOREIGN KEY (foreign_attribute) REFERENCES foreign_table(foreign_attribute), 
    PRIMARY KEY (attribute, foreign_attribute)
);
```

This somehow doesn't work, can anyone recommend an alternative solution and point out the mistake in the above?

P.S.: ABSOLUTE BEGINNER DO NOT BASH

Comment: excuseme can you explain why you want use two filed for primary key . in other word why you dont use a column as int and identity?

Comment: anyway i think you forget add a column then set it for FOREIGN KEY

Answer (score 0):

Having a foreign key column as part of a compound primary key is OK, but in any case you need to create that column before you can add the FK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    attribute int,
    foreign_attribute int REFERENCES foreign_table(foreign_attribute), 
    PRIMARY KEY (attribute, foreign_attribute)
);
```

Or if you want to choose the name of the FK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    attribute int,
    foreign_attribute int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (attribute, foreign_attribute),
    CONSTRAINT fk_foreign_table FOREIGN KEY(foreign_attribute) REFERENCES foreign_table(foreign_attribute)
);
```

The child column must have the same datatype and length as the parent column - I assumed `int`. In most databases, the parent column must be unique in the parent table (or be the primary key column).